# What are these characters: ⎲⎳?

Tags: html, character-encoding, symbols, lyx

I used Lyx (a Latex distribution) to convert my content to an HTML page.

I noticed that the sigma symbol represented in firefox is composed of these 2 characters:
⎲ ⎳

The first character is for the upper part of Sigma symbol, and second character is for the lower part. I tried to search Google for these "weird" characters but could not find anything. Do those characters even belong to ASCII? Can somebody tell me where I can find those weird characters?

Comment: Is it just me and my Firefox, or does the Questions link up top get covered by the question title because the characters are HUUUUUGE?!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It are characters which are specified by [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) which can cover over one million characters. Practically every character the mankind is aware of is specified in there. You can find details about specific Unicode characters at [fileformat.info search](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm).

- `⎲` is the [Unicode Character 'SUMMATION TOP' (U+23B2)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23b2/index.htm)
- `⎳` is the [Unicode Character 'SUMMATION BOTTOM' (U+23B3)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23b3/index.htm)

In order to be able to use them, you've to use an Unicode compatible character encoding, such as [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Using a different character encoding to present them would only result in [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Answer (score 5):

They're unicode (2-byte) chracters. If you know the encoding scheme, you can probably figure out what they are, likely [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Comment: Note that not all Unicode characters are 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

They are the Unicode characters [U+23B2 SUMMATION TOP](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23b2/index.htm) and [U+23B3 SUMMATION BOTTOM](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23b3/index.htm). They do not belong to ASCII, no.